# MySQL query, subquery, distinct, count,

Tags: mysql, sql

###### `Employees` table

| Name. | New. |
| --- | --- |
| Shadab. | Yes |
| Ali. | No |
| Shadab. | Yes |

###### Results

| Name. | New(Yes). | New(No) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shadab. | 2. | 0 |
| Ali. | . | 1 |

How can get this result from `Employees` Table? Using MySQL.

Just count `Yes` and `No` of `New` Column.

Comment: Show us your code and what have you tried. We help, we dont make your homework.

Comment: I'm using this select distinct name, count(select new from employee where new="Yes") as new_yes, count(select new from employee where new="Yes") as new_yes from employee;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name, 
    coalesce(yes.numbers, 0), 
    coalesce(no.numbers, 0) 
FROM employees AS a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, count(name) AS numbers FROM employees WHERE new = 'Yes' GROUP BY name) AS yes ON (a.name = yes.name)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT name, count(name) AS numbers FROM employees WHERE new = 'No' GROUP BY name) AS no ON (a.name = no.name)
```

or with SUM and IF:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(IF(new = 'Yes', 1, 0)) as yes_num,
    SUM(IF(new = 'No', 1, 0)) as no_num
FROM employees
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps me. Need to understand it deeply but by myself. for example, the "coalesce" function and MySQL join queries. Thanks a lot. @LordF

Comment: Coalesce mean that if first value is null, get the second, so if yes.numbers is null then 0 :) - if you change that to 'yes.numbers' you will get null instead of 0 if the name has no one 'Yes'

Answer (score 2):

[here you can check the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQXAl.png)

Here is your required Query:

```
SELECT 
Name,
SUM(CASE WHEN New='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NEW_Yes,
SUM(CASE WHEN New!='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NEW_No 
FROM `employees` 
GROUP BY Name
```